# Chemfig: isomeri equilibrium

Tags: tex, latex

I spent a lot of time looking for the right coefficients of the two arrows, in order to align the three xylenes.
There is probably a more elegant method. Could you suggest it to me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,patterns,positioning} % <---
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{%
%       %scheme debug=true,
        arrow offset=9pt,
        arrow coeff=0.7,
%       compound sep=5em,
        + sep left=0.6em,
        + sep right=0.6em,
        atom sep=1.25em,
        fixed length=true
}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{**6(---(-)-(-)--)}
    \arrow(.-20--.200){<=>}
    \chemfig{**6(--(-)--(-)--)}
    \arrow(.-18--){<=>}
    \chemfig{**6(-(-)---(-)--)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a stackexchange site dedicated cu TeX - LaTeX https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you align the chemical thingies at the top, you only need to figure out how much you want to move the arrows down -- so instead of guessing a couple of coefficients, only one is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,patterns,positioning} % <---
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{%
%       scheme debug=true,
        arrow offset=9pt,
        arrow coeff=0.7,
       compound sep=5em,
        + sep left=0.6em,
        + sep right=0.6em,
        atom sep=1.25em,
        fixed length=true
}
\begin{document}


\schemestart
    \chemfig{**6(---(-)-(-)--)}
    \arrow(.north east--.north west){<=>[][][-0.9cm]}
    \chemfig{**6(--(-)--(-)--)}
    \arrow(.north east--.north west){<=>[][][-0.9cm]}
    \chemfig{**6(-(-)---(-)--)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]